# How do I combine indirection with replacement in parameter expansion

Tags: bash

Given

```
VAR=A-B
A_B=X
```

I need to get `X` from `VAR`.

I've tried

```
$ echo ${!VAR/-/_}
-bash: A-B: invalid variable name
```

This seems to have wrong priority (`!VAR` getting expanded first).

And

```
$ echo ${!${VAR/-/_}}
-bash: ${!${VAR/-/_}}: bad substitution
```

(in the actual case I care about `VAR` is `CIRCLE_USERNAME`, my Github username happens to have a `-` in it, and I can't create a variable with `-` in the name)

Comment: Better make that `${VAR//-/_}` or @alexey-romanov-alt won't be happy.

Answer (score 3):

Of course immediately after posting this I realized nothing stops me doing

```
VAR_REPLACED=${VAR/-/_}
echo ${!VAR_REPLACED}
```

I would still be interested in how to do it in one step.

Comment: I don't think you'd get do that without the temporary variable. Bash doesn't support nested expansions in other contexts either (like `${${a#foo}%bar}`, which zsh does support). Though of course you could do `VAR=${VAR/-/_}; echo ${!VAR}` if you don't need `$VAR` anywhere else, but it's still an extra line. In a few cases namerefs would be better than the `${!var}` indirect expansion, but it doesn't really help here, as the nameref would be an additional variable too.

Comment: Perhaps `eval '${'"${VAR/-/_}"'}'`?